# How to list the articles users have read on my Opengraph integrated application

Tags: facebook-graph-api, action, facebook-opengraph

I have a news application that has Opengraph integrated and actions approved like read and watch.

I want to list all articles, videos etc that friends of a visiting user have read, watched on my application.

How do I go about doing this? Something similar to what Yahoo have done in their news page where a list of my friends who used the app show on top and onhover the articles they read shows up. Washington post also does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Activity Feed plugin: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/

If you don't want to use a plugin, you'll have to handle all the logging and building the query on your own site - this is what Washington Post do.

Comment: Yes, I do use the plugin for now. Oh so it aint as simple as querying Opengraph API for what the users friends were reading and listing them dynamically?